# Angular2: Form input haven't valid property

Tags: forms, input, angular, scope

I have this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="Signup()" name="signup">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" required [(ngModel)]="name" name="name">
    <label>
        @{{ name.valid }}
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**P.S: I use @ because I use Laravel with blade.**
If I use @{{ name }} it works!!

And I can't see if scope name is valid or not, if I set name.valid or signup.name.valid I get these:

> platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'name' of undefined

or

> platform-browser.umd.js:1900 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'valid' of undefined

On angular1 it was so simple.. now is more complicated.. I do right on the angular2 site and still got errors.. lol.

Answer (score 0):

According to new form API, **ngModel** works with **control's status** via **ngForm** directive which is missing in your case.

> The NgForm directive
>
> What NgForm directive? We didn't add an NgForm directive!
>
> Angular did. Angular creates and attaches an NgForm directive to the
>    tag automatically.
>
> The NgForm directive supplements the form element with additional
>   features. It holds the controls we created for the elements with
>   ngModel directive and name attribute and monitors their properties
>   including their validity. It also has its own valid property which is
>   true only if every contained control is valid.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="Signup()" #singupForm="ngForm">                    //<----- changed it


    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Username" 
           required [(ngModel)]="name" name="name"  #name="ngModel"> //<----- changed it

    <label>
        @{{ name.valid }}
    </label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

This should work now.